# Smart Card communication establishment in Windows

Tags: windows, smartcard, ioctl, smartcard-reader

When I insert a Smart Card to the reader after receiving ATR I can see in the driver log a number of IOCTL's that are not sent by my application (as is not running).

My question is if there is any  document, describing Smard Card communication establishment in windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the Win32 API for communicating with smart cards within Windows
platform in form SCardXXX. Similar implementation for Linux is developed under
Muscle project as PC/SC Lite API.On Windows platform Following functions will be used:

- SCardEstablishContext
- SCardListReaders
- SCardConnect
- SCardReconnect
- SCardDisconnect
- SCardReleaseContext
- SCardTransmit

Figure shows that how the smart card intract with application on windows platform.

[image]

For more information see the [Here](http://www.fi.muni.cz/~xsvenda/docs/SC_BasicsPCSC.pdf)